# Shopping Cart tables - Feedback Database Design

Tags: php, sql, database, database-design, data-structures

I am developing online shopping system.

This is how the product structure work:

There are number of categories..

Each Category has number of items.

Each Item have one or more Options

An Option can have extra(s) or without extra(s)

The following tables I have:

```
mysql> desc categories;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| cat_id     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| company_id | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name       | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Eg: 12, 2, "Google"

Items Table:

```
mysql> desc items;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| item_id     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| cat_id      | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name        | varchar(150) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description | varchar(150) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Eg: 2, 12, "Item 1", "Desc... 1"

Eg: 3, 12, "Item 2", "Desc... 2"

Options Table

```
mysql> desc items_options;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| option_id | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| item_id   | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name      | varchar(150) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| price     | decimal(6,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Eg: 45, 2, "Regular", "2.20"

Eg: 46, 3, "Small", "1.20"

Eg: 47, 3, "Large", "2.20"

Extras Table:

```
mysql> desc items_options_extras;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| extra_id  | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| option_id | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name      | varchar(150) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| price     | decimal(6,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Eg: 64, 47, "With Bag", 0.10"

Is this good database design? What could be improved?

I did not create a relationship table, is this necessary? If so, im not sure how do I create a relationship table.

At the moment I use multiple SELECT queries to get the relationship between those tables, like this below:

```
<?php
$q =  mysql_query("SELECT item_id, name FROM items where cat_id = '3'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
     echo $row['name'];
     $q2 = mysql_query("SELECT price FROM items_options_extras where item_id =" . $row['item_id']);
        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($q2))
            echo $row2['price'];
        }
}
?>
```

When I want to delete an Item and including options, I use similar php code like above.

Edit: Forgot to add Options table

Edit: Updated some data example.

Comment: Have you missed out the options table ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that. Just updated my question. Thanks!

Comment: Can you expand on what the options and extras tables are actually storing?  What kind of information?  Perhaps give us an example of a few items in the tables.  Specifically I'm interested in what relationships are one-to-one, one-to-many, and many-to-many.

Comment: This really seems like something for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Tyler, I have just added some example, please see updated question.  Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider that an Item may belong to multiple Categories.

[image]

Here are things to consider:

- If the price of an item changes with the category, then the ItemPrice column goes into the CategoryItems table. If not, it goes into the Items table.
- If the price of an option changes with the item, then the OptionPrice column goes into the ItemOptions table. If not, it goes into the Option table.

Comment: I agree with this layout.  My only question was whether or not an Item would belong to one category or multiple.  But you're break down of the relationships seems logical and of course, normalized.  Great work.

Comment: Good layout but in my business model, Item belong to one category only. I understood from your layout clearly but I would have thousands of different options name. I think you could perhaps update your layout to follow my table design a bit?

Comment: @User, if an item only belongs to one category then you only have to remove to CategoryItems table and put a CategoryId (FK) in the Items table.  Regardless if you have thousands of different options names, you need the OptionExtra to normalize your table, which is the best practice.

Comment: @user622378 - you asked what could be improved in your database design. The design I put up is normalized better.

Comment: @user622378 I have learned the hard way that one-to-many relationships soon turn into many-to-many and it is much harder to change the database later on. So I would suggest that you add the CategoryItems table to your design.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful. Could you add OrderItems tables please. Price always change in the ItemOption and it should not affect the invoice?

Comment: What data modelling software do you use? It look nice